# Python/Pandas - remove street number from address

Tags: python, regex, pandas

address in the format: 
(number) + (street name etc.)

I want street name to be left without number.

I tried:

```
df['street'] = re.sub(r'^[\d-]+ ', '', df['street'], 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your regex pattern:

```
df['street'] = df['street'].str.replace(r'^[\d-]+', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `str.rstrip`:

```
df['street'] = df['street'].str.rstrip('\d+')
```

Comment: ```TypeError: rstrip() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: My regex pattern turned out to be good. I tried to use re.sub and it didn't work. rstrip gave the error I gave in the comment above. Str.replace with my regex pattern did the trick.